TypeError: string is not a function when Array.findIdex is used
Not sure if I'm doing an error in the code, but when I try to find the index of the letter z that is in the array I've split I will get this error:
TypeError: string "z" is not a function
    at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>)

Here is the code:
const chars: string = "abcdefghilmnopqrstuwxyz0123456789@-_+*(),.#";
let outputMatrix: Array<string> = [];
let outputWord: string = "";

// Split input matrix function 
const splitMatrix = async (inputMatrix: string) => {
  let splitted = inputMatrix.split(''); 
  let uppercaseChars = splitted.findIndex('z');
  console.log(uppercaseChars)
  console.log(splitted)
  return splitted;
}

// Generating random word
const createRandomString = (splittedChars: Array<string>, length?: number) => {
  const defaultLength: number = 12;
  const min: number  = 0;
  const max: number = splittedChars.length;
  let num: number;

  if (length) {
    for(let i: number = 0; i < length; i++) {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      outputWord += splittedChars[num];
    }
    return outputWord;
  } else {
    for(let i: number = 0; i < defaultLength; i++) {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      outputWord += splittedChars[num];
    }
  }
  console.log('Generated password', outputWord);
}

const main = () => {
  splitMatrix(chars)
    .then( (outputMatrix) => {
      createRandomString(outputMatrix);
    });
}

main();

What I want to do is to get the index of the z letter and after this extract all the elements that are before the letter including the letter to uppercase them.

.findIndex() expects a function that returns true for the element you want to get the index of. You should be using .indexOf().

Indeed, you can use indexOf if you don't want to wrap it in a callback as I mentioned in my answer

Thank you. I was missing this thing of the callback. I will accept the answer. :)

The error occurs because you are passing a string ('z') directly into the findIndex method, which expects a function as its argument. The findIndex method requires a callback function that tests each element of the array to determine if it matches your criteria
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex


    const chars: string = "abcdefghilmnopqrstuwxyz0123456789@-_+*(),.#";
    let outputMatrix: Array<string> = [];
    let outputWord: string = "";
    
    // Split input matrix function 
    const splitMatrix = async (inputMatrix: string) => {
      let splitted = inputMatrix.split(''); 
      // Find the index of the letter 'z' correctly using a callback function
      let uppercaseChars = splitted.findIndex((char) => char === 'z');
      
      console.log(uppercaseChars);
      console.log(splitted);
      return splitted;
    }
    
    // Generating random word
    const createRandomString = (splittedChars: Array<string>, length?: number) => {
      const defaultLength: number = 12;
      const min: number  = 0;
      const max: number = splittedChars.length;
      let num: number;
    
      if (length) {
        for(let i: number = 0; i < length; i++) {
          num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
          outputWord += splittedChars[num];
        }
        return outputWord;
      } else {
        for(let i: number = 0; i < defaultLength; i++) {
          num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
          outputWord += splittedChars[num];
        }
      }
      console.log('Generated password', outputWord);
    }
    
    const main = () => {
      splitMatrix(chars)
        .then((outputMatrix) => {
          createRandomString(outputMatrix);
        });
    }
    
    main();



